# error CS2001: Helpers.deps.json could not be found

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application project. I have not made any changes to the code. I click on Run and I get the following error:

```
 ~\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Tag Helpers\src\Tag Helpers\error CS2001: Source file '~\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Tag Helpers\src\Tag Helpers\Helpers.deps.json' could not be found.  Tag Helpers C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

File: Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for Web. All of my previous projects are running fine. It's just that whenever I try to create a new project, I am getting this error. I have no idea why this error is coming. I also don't know what else to put here which could help get more idea on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem silly, but what I did was to completely close this solution/project and open a new one. I think the files had not loaded properly the first time I created the project.

I can be wrong, but this worked for me.